# PHP chat censorship

Tags: php, forms

I have a chat on my website, but it doesn't have accounts, so cursing is rampant. I use PHP to write all of my data to `user.txt`. Is there a simple filter for mindless cursing in php? Because this `js` I use doesn't seem to work too well:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input:submit[name='submit']").on("click",function() {
    var name = $("input:text[name='name']").val();
    var message = $("input:text[name='field2']").val();
    var badwords = ["dingbat", "poopy"];

    /* do this */ 

    if($.inArray(name, badwords) !==-1 || $.inArray(message, badwords) !==-1) {
      alert("Your Message Contains Bad Words, Please Remove Them Before Proceeding");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my full code (minus `txt.php` which just displays `user.txt`)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300);
 #blu {
 background: #F0FAFF;
 padding: 3;
width: 310;
        }
  b, i, p {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 23px;
    line-height: 1.4375rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family:"Lato";
}
iframe{border: 3px solid white;}

button,input, #rcp_submit, #rcp_update_card {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: black;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 9px 16px !important;
    line-height: 1.4;
    border: 0;
 color:black;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 0.1s;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
```

```html
,!--this file is called c5.php-->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "<br>";
    $ret = file_put_contents('user.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
 echo "$ret bytes written to file<a href ='javascript:history.go(-1)'>go back</a>";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
?>
<html>
<body onload="reloadIFrame();">
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 3000);
function reloadIFrame() {
 document.getElementById("myIframe").src="txt.php";
}
</script>
<div id ="blu">
<table>
<p>Chat about your code</p>
<td>
<iframe src ="txt.php" id ="myIframe"></iframe><br/>
<button onclick="reloadIFrame();">Refresh feed</button>
<form action="c5.php" method="POST">
<p>Name:</p>
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
 <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<p>Question:<p>
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<a href="user.txt" download="chatlogs">download chat logs</a>
</td>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: will never work, people will always find creative ways to c_u_r_s_e

Comment: Such a JS based filter should work perfectly well, assuming that you have a valid and complete catalog of words you want to filter out. So what is the issue? What do you actually mean by "doesn't seem to work too well"?

Comment: And a general question: how come that people appear to be so angry when visiting your site that they curse? That is not common in the internet...

Comment: @arkascha it really is... OP: whitelists rarely work, it might put people off if they get warned and temp-banned (some people find pride in their screen names). Without people being authenticated (logged in) you can't really ban them, but you can destroy their session and temp ban their nick (if you let them choose one), or something..

Comment: I just want to autodelete cusses, later I ac update my db to ban c-u-s-s-e-s

Answer (score 0):

let's take a look at why your js was not working

**You are matching a whole sentence for a word .**
here is an example if the `var name` is `BADWORD SOMEONE_BADWORD` 
what you are searching if the array holds that value (`BADWORD SOMEONE_BADWORD`)

so what you should do is split the sentence into it's basic component **words**

```
name.split(/[(\s|_)]/) // split the name by white space or underscore
```

now you will have an array of

`["BADWORD", "SOMEONE", "BADWORD"]`

and the code becomes:

```
$(function() {
  function containBadWord(words , banlist){
    var bad = false;
    $.each(words , function(k , v){
        if($.inArray(v, banlist) !==-1){
           bad = true;
           return false;
        }
    });
    return bad;
  }
  $("input:submit[name='submit']").on("click",function() {
    var name = $("input:text[name='']").val(); 
    var name_split = name.split(/[(\s|_)]/); 
    var message = $("input:text[name='field2']").val();
    var message_split = message .split(/[(\s|_)]/); 
    var badwords = ["dingbat", "poopy"];

    /* do this */ 
    if(containBadWord(name_split , badwords )){
     alert("your name has bad words")
    }

    if(containBadWord(message_split , badwords )){
     alert("your messagehas bad words")
    }
  });
});
```

## edit :

the code above was not working because your jquery selectors are all wrong as well .

```
`input:text[name='']` will select an input with an empty attribute of `name`
```

here is working code

https://jsfiddle.net/tq7odeLg/

Comment: i hope for more than doesnt  work comment , but i'll ask what doesnt work! i tested it out and it worked for me

Comment: is there some way to achieve this with php?

Comment: after all the question was: **PHP** chat censorship

Comment: well im sure there is a way .. but my php is rusty .. also you edited the tags and removed the javascript tag ... which is was a total waste of my time ... we brows questions by tag ... and in your question it states `Because this js I use doesn't seem to work too ` which means you are okay with eaither a js or php fix , you posted your js too which made it more and more a js issue ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and it worked:

```html
<?php

$find=array('bad','word','words');

$replace=array('...','...','...');

if(isset($_POST['user_input'])&&!empty($_POST['user_input']))
     $data = $_POST['name'] . '-' . $_POST['user_input'] . "<br>";
$ret = file_put_contents('user.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
    }
{

$user_input=$_POST['user_input'];

$user_input_new=str_ireplace($find,$replace,$user_input);

}
?>

<p>    <?php 
        $text = file_get_contents('user.txt');
        echo $text;
    ?>
</p>
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300);
b, i, p {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 23px;
    line-height: 1.4375rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family:"lato";
}
</style>

<hr>

<form action="ws.php" method="POST">
<p>name:</p><input name ="name" type ="text"></input><br/>
<p>comment:</p><br/><textarea name="user_input" rows="6" col="30">
</textarea><br/>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</form>
```